# How to develop a Phone Gap splash for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

i am just wondering about this thing that, how do i able to create a splash screen in android using Phone gap.But, i did not find the right way to do this :( 
here is some code that i am using .. It shows up a black screen and then index.html page
Start Activity is written below:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);
```

Javascript code in index.html header:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // Cordova is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
    }
```

Comment: Do u have splash.jpg or splash.png in your res folder?

Comment: yea it is there but only in hdpi folder and it is a nine patch image

Comment: Copy it in all folders and check

Comment: No it is not working at all... can you have some samples that i can download and try ?

Comment: retry with cleaning the project

Comment: If still doesnt work try with fresh project refering phonegap docs

Comment: Oh thanks dearest brother cleaning project works for me :)